# MySql/Rails - Group by two columns with different value in one

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i have problem group query

```
cmpid = [222,232,343,232,232]    
ProductAttribute.select(:txt,:val).where("cmpid IN (?)", cmpid).group(:txt)
```

Tabel looks

```
-----------------------
id | txt  | val | cmpid
-----------------------
1    aaa   ddd   222
2    aaa   eee   232
3    aaa   ddd   343
4    bbb   ded   232
5    vvv   ddd   232
```

But when I group id by txt its not return txt=>"vvv" because it's grouped by "ddd" value - and its correct (sql sense) but how to group items with check whether :txt is also same or different?

Comment: i don't know ruby but you need to group by all non-aggregate columns so i would expect you need to write .group(:txt,:val), but I don't think you need a group by here, so try "ProductAttribute.select(:txt,:val).where("cmpid IN (?)", cmpid)" without .group

Comment: then I will get 300 records - its must by grouped by 'val' with somehow considering :txt column

Comment: Can you edit and put the expected result ?

Comment: `:txt=>aaa,:val=>ddd(only once becouse its same)*,
:txt=>aaa,:val=>eee (this one is gruped but if val is another it's show it also)
:txt=>bbb,:val=>ded`

Comment: It's what I said .group(:txt,:val)